# How to update the applicationbadge number when application is not running?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented APNS in my application .

It works like a charm .

There is just one problem that i don't know how to update the badge number if two subsequent 
notifications come and the application is not yet launched .

suppose first time is 1 then 2 just like the mail application .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported, not even with the "multitasking" feature in iOS 4.

Comment: or they are counting total number of mails and then send the bedge . what is the logic

Comment: Apple does what they want. They are not bound by the restrictions they set for third-party developers.